# Cannot access Jupyter lab on Google Cloud Platform. Cannot find template: "403.html"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, http-status-code-403, jupyter-lab

I have a virtual machine on Google Cloud Platform. I left a code running on Jupyter lab, which I accessed through port 8080, and I was checking its proper functioning using Google cloud shell once in a while. This processess worked fine for almost two weeks, but suddenly when I tried to web preview on port 8080, this message appears: Cannot find template: "403.html" In "/opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab/static".

Any ideas how can I solve this and have access to my jupyter lab on port 8080 ?

Comment: Are you using a VM image from [AI Platform Deep Learning](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/images)? In this case the web preview in Cloud Shell is not supported and you need to follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter) in order to access JupyterLab. Otherwise, could you elaborate about how you created your JupyterLab and the steps followed to access it by the web preview ?

Comment: I created a [Deep Learning VM](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning), activated Cloud Sheel and typed "gcloud compute ssh --project projectname --zone us-zonename virtualmachinename -- -L 8080:localhost:8080". After that, I clicked on "Web Preview" next to "Terminal Settings" and press "Preview on Port 8080. I did this multiple times, and it worked. A new window opened with JupyerLab and the code I was running. But suddently, I got the message: Cannot find template: "403.html" In "/opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab/static", using the same steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed a test and I got the same error, but after I enabled the [Notebooks API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/notebooks.googleapis.com/overview)
the message disappeared and I was able to open the JupyterLab. I suggest that you check if the aforementioned API is enabled, if not try by enabling it.

As an additional workaround, you can try accessing from another environment (like your local computer) by running  the [gcloud commands](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter) within it, please notice that it’s required to have the  [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs)  installed.

In case both options don't work for you, I recommend you to contact the [Google Cloud Platform support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) this according to your [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs), so they can check if there is a specific issue with your VM.

Answer (score 1):

I found I in that situation was missing setting `c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True`, Otherwise you should check `c.NotebookApp.ip`. In some cluster you should set `c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'` rather than `*`.